# Visual Studio 2012: Sign Symbol in Property Symbol

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I noticed a symbol in the Watch Window that I have never seen before. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Unrecognized Symbol]

What does this mean? When I wouldn't have access, why can I see the value then?  I already looked on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/y47ychfe(v=vs.110)), but it is not listed. Does anyone know what this symbol means?

**NOTE:** I am referring to the icon on the left.<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747254/visual-studio-2012-sign-symbol-in-property-symbol#comment20637788_14747254)</sup>.

Comment: which one of the symbols?

Comment: have you tried using the value to check if you actually don't have access, or are you just assuming you don't have access? What have you tried (to do with it)?

Comment: @Shane It tells me: "Cannot access internal indexer 'this' here". I used the command: string test = database.DB.Columns["ID"][0].ToString()

Comment: So, the sign just tells me I don't have access to this variable from my current place because it is internal?

Comment: This is surely not the Object Browser. Perhaps a debug window...

Comment: @leppie Yes you're right. Sorry, I edited it

Comment: Apparently, it's a property: https://twitter.com/yetanotherchris/statuses/246664235231371265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it, reminded this post and decided to answer it.

This just says the property has the access modifier `internal`.

That's it, nothing more.